# Issue in joining the image and description in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been created time-line for my web page, by using html,css3 and js.

html:

```
  <div class="cntl-state">
      <div class="cntl-content">
        <h4>Title 4</h4>
        <p>India’s Saina Nehwal won the Australian Badminton Open Super Series title at the State Sports Centre in Sydney on 29 June, 2014. Saina began the match in aggressive fashion as she raced into a 12-8 lead in the first game against Spain’s Carolina Marin in the final.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cntl-image"><img src="img/timelinesn-12.jpg" alt="tm12"></div>
      <div class="cntl-icon cntl-center">2014</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
    .cntl-center {
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.cntl-bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px -2px #000;
}

.cntl-bar-fill {
    background-color: #66cc00;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:0;

}

.cntl-state {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.cntl-state::after {
    display:block;
    content: ' ';
    clear:both;
}

.cntl-icon {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #003300;
    border: solid 3px #009900;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px -9px #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

.cntl-content {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.25);
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #009900;
    float:left;
    opacity:0;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-40%;
}

.cntl-state:nth-child(2n+2) .cntl-content {
    float:right;
    margin-right:-40%;
}

.cntl-image {
    opacity:0;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 2%;
}

.cntl-state:nth-child(2n+1) .cntl-image {
    float:right;
}

.cntl-content h4 {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*
animations
*/
.cntl-bar-fill,.cntl-content,.cntl-image {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.cntl-state:nth-child(2n+2).cntl-animate .cntl-content {
    margin-right:6%;
}

.cntl-animate .cntl-content {
    opacity:1;
    margin-left:6%;
}

.cntl-animate .cntl-image {
    opacity:1;
}
```

And i have used js files also, i m trying to create jsfiddle, but can't able to get.

Now my page shows like this http://s30.postimg.org/54dkm4qoh/Untitled_2.png

I need like this dotted line, for joint the image and description.

http://s30.postimg.org/k522y658x/Untitled_1.png

Can anyone help me to give idea for creating dotted line that is join the both image and description?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, StackOverflow is a Q&A forum. It's not about people writing code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to draw dotted line here is the code for it.

```
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style id="TempStyle"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <hr style="height: 0;margin:50px;width: 200px;border-width: 5px;border-color: black;border-style: dotted;"><!-- horizontal line -->
    <hr style="height: 200px;margin:50px;width: 0px;border-width: 5px;border-color: black;border-style: dotted;"><!-- vertical line -->
    </body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: matter is, how to join my image and description using this dotted line..?

Answer (score 0):

Actually its little messy when we try using CSS to do these sort of things. Still i think this is what you might be looking for [Demo](http://divyashah.in/timeline/). I have just showed you the quick demo, but you will have to add cross browser support.

**CSS** & **HTML**

```css
html, body {
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}

body{
color:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
}

.leftcont
{
position:absolute;
margin-left:0%;
display:block;
width:47%;
height:100%;
background:#333;
}

.timeline
{
position:absolute;
margin-left:47%;
display:block;
width:6%;
height:100%;
background:#ddd;
}

.rightcont
{
position:absolute;
margin-left:53%;
display:block;
width:48%;
height:100%;
background:#333;
}

.content1
{
padding:20px;
display:block;
height:150px;
width:200px;
float:right;
margin-right:10%;
margin-top:10%;
background:#ddd;
color:black;
}

.content2
{
padding:20px;
display:block;
height:150px;
width:200px;
float:left;
margin-left:10%;
margin-top:10%;
background:#ddd;
color:black;
}

.circle
{
display:block;
height:60px;
width:60px;
margin-top:100%;
border-radius:50%;
background:#000;
padding:15px 15px;
text-align:center;
font-size:22px;
}

#linel
{
position:relative;
float:right;
right:-44%;
top:17%;
display:block;
width:70px;
height:0.1px;
border:2px dashed green;
}

#liner
{
position:relative;
float:left;
left:-43%;
top:17%;
display:block;
width:65px;
height:0.1px;
border:2px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftcont">
  
 <div class="content1">India's Saina Nehwal won the Australian Badminton Open Super Series title at the State Sports Centre in Sydney on 29 June, 2014.</div>
 <span id="linel"></span>
</div>
<div class="timeline">
 <div class="circle">2006</div>
</div/>
<div class="rightcont">
 <div class="content2">India's Saina Nehwal won the Australian Badminton Open Super Series title at the State Sports Centre in Sydney on 29 June, 2014.</div>
 <span id="liner"></span> 
</div/>
```

Comment: Well it works "even in my Internet Explorer", so i don't know what's wrong with this demo, but still thing is you can use border: 1px dashed #color, property of CSS. This is what i tried to explain in this above Demo.

Comment: i know, how to create dotted line in vertically or horizontally... I want to know how to join exactly with image and description.